# How to create a model in XAML and assign values to it

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding

I've some weird case that I'm trying to accomplish:

I've one "Converter" that require me to provide multiples values in parameters. One of this value is a class. I wanted to create a class containing those parameters:

```
<ContentControl ContentTemplateSelector="{StaticResource ConventionBasedDataTemplateSelector}" >
    <ContentControl.Content>
        <Binding Path="SelectedNode">
            <Binding.Converter>
                <converters:NodeToViewModel  />
            </Binding.Converter>
            <Binding.ConverterParameter>
                <converters:NodeToViewModelParameters ViewContext="{x:Static viewModelRegister:ViewContext.LiveView}">
                    <converters:NodeToViewModelParameters.Parameters>
                        <converters:Parameters SomeParameter="{Binding Something}" SomeOtherParameter="{Binding SomethingElse}"/>
                    </converters:NodeToViewModelParameters.Parameters>
                </converters:NodeToViewModelParameters>
            </Binding.ConverterParameter>
        </Binding>
    </ContentControl.Content>
</ContentControl>
```

But when it tries to assign `Something` to `SomeParameter`, I get an error:

```
'A 'Binding' cannot be set on the 'SomeParameter' property of type 'Parameters'. A 'Binding' can only be set on a DependencyProperty of a DependencyObject.'
```

Is there a way to create a model from the XAML, taking some parameters coming from the ViewModel?

Comment: Use a MultiBinding with an IMultiValueConverter.

Comment: @Clemens It tasught of it, but it doesn't change that one of this value is a class(Parameters) that needs values from different parts. 
Also, I don't like much this idea, because in some case I've other kind of converter parameters, which doesn't require this additional parameter, so I will end by having different converter of just one that can handle a null.

Comment: Can't you break the parameters into: `<converters:Parameters><converters:Parameters.SomeParameter><InstanceOfClassYouAlreadyHave/><converters:Parameters.SomeParameter/><converters:Parameters/>`?

Comment: @XAMlMAX Not because I know the parameter is forwarded to a service with an interface as parameter, and only the view knows which implementation of this interface is supposed to be used.

Comment: XAML is in the view so you should have the correct implementation at that point. "_Is there a way to create a model from the XAML, taking some parameters coming from the ViewModel?_" - yes you can. Model has to have a default constructor though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is trying to stretch the `IValueConverter` framework a bit too far - you could have your converters implement `DependencyObject` to allow Binding but I think you will run in to trouble getting these to fire due to how these are instantiated from the xaml.

I'd recommend the [Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Wpf](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Wpf/) nuget package - this allows you to attach `Behavior` instances that already extend `DependencyObject` and support Binding out of the box. Once the binding fires you can then set the `Content` on the `ContentControl` you're attached to via whatever logic you want.

For example:

```cs
public class NodeToViewModelBehavior : Behavior<ContentControl>
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty NodeProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Node", typeof(object), typeof(NodeToViewModelBehavior), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(PropertyChangedCallback));

    public object Node
    {
        get { return (object) GetValue(NodeProperty); }
        set { SetValue(NodeProperty, value); }
    }

    private static void PropertyChangedCallback(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var nodeToViewModelBehavior = (NodeToViewModelBehavior)d;
        var newNode = e.NewValue;
        nodeToViewModelBehavior.SetContent(newNode);
    }

    private void SetContent(object newNode)
    {
        var convertedObject = newNode; // insert logic here to grab whatever data you need
        this.AssociatedObject.Content = convertedObject;
    }
}
```

And usage in xaml as follows:

```xml
<ContentControl>
    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <local:NodeToViewModelBehavior Node="{Binding SelectedNode}"/>
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
</ContentControl>
```

where namespace i is declared as

```
xmlns:i="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors;assembly=Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors"
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems interesteting approach. thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You may create a converter that implements both interfaces, IValueConverter and IMultiValueConverter:

```
public class NodeToViewModel : IValueConverter, IMultiValueConverter
{
    private object Convert(
        object value, NodeToViewModelParameters parameters = null)
    {
        // do the actual conversion here, either with or without parameters
    }

    public object Convert(
        object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return Convert(value);
    }

    public object Convert(
        object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return Convert(
            values[0],
            new NodeToViewModelParameters
            {
                SomeParameter = values[1],
                SomeOtherParameter = values[2]
            });
    }

    public object ConvertBack(
        object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(
        object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

Then use it with a MultiBinding:

```
<ContentControl.Content>
    <MultiBinding>
        <MultiBinding.Converter>
            <converters:NodeToViewModel/>
        </MultiBinding.Converter>
        <Binding Path="SelectedNode"/>
        <Binding Path="Something"/>
        <Binding Path="SomethingElse"/>
    </Binding>
</ContentControl.Content>
```

Comment: I cannot, the converter has to call a service with a parameter, that is an interface. The converter is used at multiple places and doesn't know which implementation of the interface is supposed to be called, only the view knows.

Comment: Pass all necessary parameters via the child Bindings of the MultiBinding. E.g. add `<Binding Source="{x:Static viewModelRegister:ViewContext.LiveView}"/>`

Comment: Okay, but who will create the `Parameters` class that has to be provided to my service then?

Comment: But the converter doesn't know which implementation should be used, it will depends on where the converter is used. The ViewContext is the only property that will always be present for this converter, the other one could be present, totally different. It's some values that comes from this view, that will be injected in another ViewModel.

Comment: You can still add a property to the converter class that controls its behavior, and set it in XAML.

Comment: Sorry, not possible, this converter is used in different applications, I will have like 20 differents implementations of those parameters, I'm not looking for a way to have a switch with 20 cases, some of them not even being valid for this application, and then have to typecast all the next arguments for each of the 20 cases.

Comment: Well, then just write different converters for different applications. If they share a common behaviour, derive them from a common base class.